# I am trying to integrate charts in my Remix application ,Can I really do that , if yes then how?

Tags: chart.js, server-side-rendering, remix, react-chartjs-2

I used reat-chartjs-2 library and it throws an error

No "exports" main defined in ...path/node_modules/react-chartjs-2/package.json

I tried resolving those error but not able to find out how to integrate charts in server side rendering especially in Remix